# Playing .mp3 file gives AACPlayer 'Cannot start native decoder' error

Tags: android, mp3, aac

Firstly, apologies, I'm not that advanced with Java.

I have an app that I'm looking after which streams live audio (.mp3 and/or .aac) which works fine.

I have tried to get it to play an .mp3 file (not live stream, but from an http:// location which exists and is available to, say, VLC) but it crashes out with the error below.

I was hoping that the AACPlayer would also be able to play a 'static' .mp3 file but it would appear to not like it.

Happy to provide any code that may be relevant. I guess at the moment I'm just wanting to know if it is at all possible, or not, before I spend too much time on it.

Thank you.

```
V/RadioManager: RadioManagerLog : IsPlaying : false
V/RadioManager: RadioPlayerService : Play requested.
W/LOG: Cannot set the ICY URLStreamHandler - maybe already set ? - java.lang.Error: factory already defined
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
V/RadioManager: RadioManagerLog : IsPlaying : false
D/AACPlayer: header: key=null, val=HTTP/1.1 200 OK
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Accept-Ranges, val=bytes
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Connection, val=Keep-Alive
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Content-Length, val=52654208
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Content-Type, val=audio/mpeg
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Date, val=Thu, 15 Feb 2018 12:31:54 GMT
D/AACPlayer: header: key=ETag, val="3237080-5651a72245219"
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Keep-Alive, val=timeout=5, max=100
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Last-Modified, val=Tue, 13 Feb 2018 16:25:42 GMT
D/AACPlayer: header: key=Server, val=Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
D/AACPlayer: header: key=X-Android-Received-Millis, val=1518697916374
D/AACPlayer: header: key=X-Android-Response-Source, val=NETWORK 200
D/AACPlayer: header: key=X-Android-Selected-Protocol, val=http/1.1
D/AACPlayer: header: key=X-Android-Sent-Millis, val=1518697916213
I/MultiPlayer: Setting MP3 decoder for content type audio/mpeg
I/AACPlayer: This stream does not provide dynamic metainfo
V/RadioManager: RadioPlayerService : Player started. tate : PLAYING
D/BufferReader: init(): capacity=3200
I/Decoder: start() starting native decoder - OpenCORE-MP3
D/BufferReader: next() waiting....
D/BufferReader: run() started....
D/BufferReader: next() awaken
D/Decoder: start() SYNC word found at offset=0
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 2 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=2
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 1024 bytes, status=12
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 12 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 1024 bytes, status=12
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 12 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 576 bytes, status=12
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 12 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 288 bytes, status=12
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 12 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 144 bytes, status=12
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 12 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 72 bytes, status=12
D/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() Status[0]: 12 - consumed 0 bytes
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() frame decode error=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() first frame cannot be decoded - trying to sync again
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() cannot re-sync the stream after next 36 bytes, status=12
E/Decoder[OpenCORE-MP3]: start() init failed status=12
E/Decoder: start() failed err=-1
I/Decoder: stop() stopping native decoder
D/BufferReader: run() stopped.
V/RadioManager: RadioPlayerService : Player stopped. State : STOPPED
E/AACPlayer: playAsync():
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start native decoder
                 at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.start(Decoder.java:238)
                 at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.playImpl(AACPlayer.java:424)
                 at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:386)
                 at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:338)
                 at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:296)
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
W/LOG: Cannot set the ICY URLStreamHandler - maybe already set ? - java.lang.Error: factory already defined
V/RadioManager: RadioPlayerService : ERROR OCCURED.
```

Comment: An AAC codec will not be able to handle MP3.  How did you end up with the AAC codec anyway?  The log seems to indicate MP3 was used.  It's almost as if you're using some sort of library to unwrap ADTS (not generally used with MP3), and it's mangling the MP3 data before sending it to the MP3 codec.

Comment: Hi @Brad, thanks for your reply. It plays live MP3 streams correctly though. The AAC codec was used so that the app could handle both MP3 and AAC streams, which is does. It just doesn't seem to be able to play 'static' MP3 files. I admit I haven't tried to use AAC files instead of the MP3 ones, that should probably be a test I need to do.